# Remove formatting while copy value

Tags: javascript

i have following code,which copy value of one field into another one.My question is how can i remove formatting and pass it to second field.value of "b1" field is 8,760,000 (as it is money value)..so basically i need to remove "," before paste it into "b2" field

```
var b1= document.getElementById("ttl");
var b2= document.getElementById("fld_2452001_1");
b2.value = b1.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use things like `.replace()` if there are only a few characters that need to be replaced. But if there is a lot I recommend a library like he.js.

Example using `.replace()`

```js
// will replace ',' with '' (empty)
elementOne.value = elementTwo.value.replace(',', '')
```

edit: also if you only want the content of the html and not the tags as well, use `.innerText` not `.innerHTML`